# How do you write $A A^T$ in Einstein notation?

Tags: tensors

In index notation it makes sense as

$$\sum_j {A_{ij} A_{jk}^T} = \sum_j {A_{ij} A_{kj}}$$

But this doesn't make sense for Einstein notation where in

$$A^\mu_\sigma (A^\sigma_\nu)^T = A^\mu_\sigma A^\nu_\sigma  $$

and the sum is taken over both covariant indices, which is incorrect.

Also how do you know when to include a transpose when going from Einstein notation to matrix notation? For example:

$$\Lambda^\mu_\sigma \eta_{\mu\nu} \Lambda^\nu_\rho = \Lambda^T \eta \Lambda$$

How do you know that one of the lambdas is transposed?

Answer (score 2):

To define $A^{\mathsf{T}}$ within the Ricci calculus, we need a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form $g$:
$$g(x,Ay)=g(A^{\mathsf{T}}x,y)\text{.}$$
Note that the definition of $(\quad)^{\mathsf{T}}$ depends on the $g$ we choose. If the components of $g$ are $g_{ij}$ and those of its dual are $g^{ij}$, then
$${{(A^{\mathsf{T}} )}^i}_j=g^{il}{A^{k}}_lg_{kj}$$
$${{(AA^{\mathsf{T}})}^{i}}_j={A^i}_m{{(A^{\mathsf{T}} )}^m}_j=g_{ik}g^{jl}{A^i}_j{A^k}_l\text{.}$$

"$\Lambda^{\mathsf{T}}\eta\Lambda$" is an *abus de notation* that I wish physicists would avoid.

Comment: n i c e . . . .

Answer (score 0):

Follow this hint:
$$(AA^{\top})^i{}_j=A^i{}_s(A^{\top})^s{}_j$$
$$\qquad =A^i{}_s\ A^j{}_s$$

You can verify for with
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
A^1{}_1&A^1{}_2\\
A^2{}_1&A^2{}_2
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
A^1{}_1&A^2{}_1\\
A^1{}_2&A^2{}_2
\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
A^1{}_1A^1{}_1+A^1{}_2A^1{}_2&A^1{}_1A^2{}_1+A^1{}_2A^2{}_2\\
A^2{}_1A^1{}_1+A^2{}_2A^1{}_2&A^2{}_1A^2{}_1+A^2{}_2A^2{}_2
\end{array}\right]$$